# running .net application from c++

Tags: c++, .net, clr

I have a byte array of a .NET application inside c++ code.
I want to execute this .NET application without writing those bytes on the disk. `ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain` expects a path to the assembly so it's out of the equation here. I'm looking for a possible way (or hack) to pass the binary directly to the clr.

So what i can do ?

Comment: You can use the `_AppDomain` interface in native C++.  Which lets you call its Load(byte[]) method.  Use ICorRuntimeHost::GetDefaultDomain().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//todo error checks/cleanup
HRESULT hr;
ICLRMetaHost *pMetaHost = NULL;
ICLRRuntimeInfo *pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
ICorRuntimeHost *pCorRuntimeHost = NULL;
IUnknownPtr spAppDomainThunk = NULL;
_AppDomainPtr spDefaultAppDomain = NULL;
bstr_t bstrAssemblyName(L"");
_AssemblyPtr spAssembly = NULL;
bstr_t bstrClassName(L"");
_TypePtr spType = NULL;
variant_t vtEmpty;
bstr_t bstrStaticMethodName(L"Main");
variant_t vtLengthRet;
hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMetaHost));
const wchar_t* pszVersion = L"v2.0.50727";
hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(pszVersion, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
BOOL fLoadable;
hr = pRuntimeInfo->IsLoadable(&fLoadable);
if (!fLoadable) { wprintf(L".NET runtime %s cannot be loaded\n", pszVersion); return; }
hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CorRuntimeHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pCorRuntimeHost));
hr = pCorRuntimeHost->Start();
hr = pCorRuntimeHost->GetDefaultDomain(&spAppDomainThunk);
hr = spAppDomainThunk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spDefaultAppDomain));
SAFEARRAYBOUND bounds[1];
bounds[0].cElements = array_len;
bounds[0].lLbound = 0;
SAFEARRAY* arr = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, bounds);
SafeArrayLock(arr);
memcpy(arr->pvData, bytearray, array_len);
SafeArrayUnlock(arr);
hr = spDefaultAppDomain->Load_3(arr, &spAssembly);
hr = spAssembly->GetType_2(bstrClassName, &spType);
hr = spType->InvokeMember_3(bstrStaticMethodName, static_cast<BindingFlags>(BindingFlags_InvokeMethod | BindingFlags_Static | BindingFlags_Public), NULL, vtEmpty, nullptr, &vtLengthRet);
SafeArrayDestroy(arr);
```